# Nvidia Driver on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I am trying to install nvidia drivers with the instruction:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends nvidia-410
```

This command is giving me an error that I do not understand, and to be honest, I never seen it before:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nvidia-410 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                      xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                      xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                      xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                      xorg-video-abi-15 but it is not installable or
                      xorg-video-abi-18 but it is not installable or
                      xorg-video-abi-19 but it is not installable or
                      xorg-video-abi-20 or
                      xorg-video-abi-23 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What can I do? How can I install such dependencies?

Edit: Manual Installation failed with the following message:

```
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Sat Mar 14 16:38:11 2020
installer version: 418.113

PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

nvidia-installer command line:
./nvidia-installer

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses v6 user interface
-> Detected 8 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 8.
ERROR: An NVIDIA kernel module 'nvidia-drm' appears to already be 
loaded in your kernel.  This may be because it is in use (for example, 
by an X server, a CUDA program, or the NVIDIA Persistence Daemon), but
this may also happen if your kernel was configured without support for
module unloading.  Please be sure to exit any programs that may be 
using the GPU(s) before attempting to upgrade your driver.  If no GPU-
based programs are running, you know that your kernel supports module 
unloading, and you still receive this message, then an 
error may have occured that has corrupted an NVIDIA kernel module's     
usage count, for which the simplest remedy is to reboot your computer.
```

Comment: What Nvidia card do you have?

Comment: It is a laptop card: GeForce GT740M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeForce GT740M

Download and install the 418.1130 driver from https://www.geforce.com/drivers or https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/153717 for the direct download.

**Update #1:**

The install error is probably due to the Nvidia software you tried to install before. Do `dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii` and uninstall all of the old Nvidia stuff, then reboot. Retry install.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It failed. I put more details below

Comment: I do not have any output to the command `dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii`, however it still fails

Comment: @MarcoDeVirgilis Did you reboot, as I mention in my Update #1?

Comment: Right, I forgot, about that. Now it is working. Basically I am trying to follow this guide here https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/installation/gpu/local_gpu/ and it mentions driver 4.10. Do you think if I install 4.18 will work anyway?

Comment: @MarcoDeVirgilis Hard to say. The tensorflow web page is pretty old. I'd install 4.18 and get that working on Ubuntu 19.10 first. Then proceed with the tensorflow installs/etc.

Comment: @MarcoDeVirgilis  You may need to start a new question if you have tensorflow install issues. My answer addresses your current question, and that's probably solved, so please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, I have one last question. I actually need the 4.10 driver version. How do I unistall the manually installed driver? the command `dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii` is not showing it

Comment: @MarcoDeVirgilis  It doesn't look like 4.10 will work with Ubuntu 19.10. Why do you think that you need 4.10 and/or 4.18 won't work? Is it because of CUDA 10.0? I'd suggest that you contact the tensorflow support folks next.

Comment: @MarcoDeVirgilis Also see https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#linux_setup for more install instructions.

Comment: @MarcoDeVirgilis see if `dpkg -l *force* | grep ii` finds it.